# how to get fancybox textbox value after closing fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

How to get fancybox textbox value after closing fancybox...I have tried like this

```
'onStart' : function(){
        x = $('#fancybox-frame').contents().find('#comment_count').val();
        alert(x);
 },
 'onClosed': function(){
        x = $('#fancybox-frame').contents().find('#comment_count').val();
        alert(x);
 }
```

and Iam declaring var x at top of script also but it displayng undefined both the times....can anyone suggest me the correct way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onClosed` will be executed when all the fancybox content has removed so it  gives undefined.use `onCleanup` its able to give value of x after closing fancybox .

```
"onCleanup": function(){
  x = $('#fancybox-frame').contents().find('#comment_count').val();
  alert(x);
},
"onClosed": function(){
  x = $('#fancybox-frame').contents().find('#comment_count').val(); //opt
  alert(x); //opt
}
```